# Should I protect my database from invalid data?

Tags: validation, database-design

I always tend to "protect" my persistance layer from violations via the service layer. However, I am beginning to wonder if it's really necessary. What's the point in taking the time in making my database robust, building relationships & data integrity when it never actually comes into play.

For example, consider a `User` table with a unique contraint on the `Email` field. I would naturally want to write blocker code in my service layer to ensure the email being added isn't already in the database *before* attempting to add anything. In the past I have never really seen anything wrong with it, however, as I have been exposed to more & more best practises/design principles I feel that this approach isn't very [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

So, is it correct to always ensure data going to the persistance layer is indeed "valid" or is it more natural to let the invalid data get to the database and handle the error?

Comment: Garbage in, garbage out.

Comment: @njk but that's kinda my point, the data will *never* be added to the database. The question is really about whether it's right to duplicate business rules between the different layers.

Comment: There is performance advantages to having data integrity.

Comment: you aren't repeating yourself if you put the rules in the db and then autogenerate the rules for the app server and maybe client layer. or if you relay the rules results to the app server or client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though there isn't a conclusive answer, I think it's a great question.

First, I am a big proponent of including at least basic validation in the database and letting the database do what it is good at. At minimum, this means foreign keys, `NOT NULL` where appropriate, strongly typed fields wherever possible (e.g. don't put a text field where an integer belongs), unique constraints, etc. Letting the database handle concurrency is also paramount (as @Branko Dimitrijevic pointed out) and transaction atomicity should be owned by the database.

If this is moderately redundant, than so be it. Better too much validation than too little.

However, I am of the opinion that the business tier should be aware of the validation it is performing even if the logic lives in the database.

- It may be easier to distinguish between exceptions and validation errors. In most languages, a failed data operation will probably manifest as some sort of exception. Most people (me included) are of the opinion that it is bad to use exceptions for regular program flow, and I would argue that email validation failure (for example) is not an "exceptional" case.

  Taking it to a more ridiculous level, imagine hitting the database just to determine if a user had filled out all required fields on a form.

  In other words, I'd rather call a method `IsEmailValid()` and receive a boolean than try to have to determine if the database error which was thrown meant that the email was already in use by someone else.

  This approach may also perform better, and avoid annoyances like skipped IDs because an INSERT failed (speaking from a SQL Server perspective).

  The logic for validating the email might very well live in a reusable stored procedure if it is more complicated than simply a unique constraint.

  And ultimately, that simple unique constraint provides final protection in case the business tier makes a mistake.
- Some validation simply doesn't need to make a database call to succeed, even though the database could easily handle it.
- Some validation is more complicated than can be expressed using database constructs/functions alone.
- Business rules across applications may differ even against the same (completely valid) data.
- Some validation is so critical or expensive that it should happen prior to data access.
- Some simple constraints like field type/length can be automated (anything run through an ORM probably has some level of automation available).

Comment: +1 this is more along the lines of the type of response I was after. I agree with *basic* validation being done at the service layer i.e. checking for required fields etc. it was more validation that would require DB interaction I was concerned about (like duplicate checking). So to summarise, would you conclude that it *is* infact normal to have this layer of "protection" between the service/DB layers?

Comment: Using the duplicate checking for user names/emails as an example, I would enforce that at the database using a unique constraint as a failsafe but I would perform the check using the business tier (calling the database with a `SELECT` rather than an `INSERT`). This avoids throwing an exception and lets you do more with the return value, like suggesting alternate usernames. In general, I'm of the opinion that bad/erroneous data should be stopped as soon as possible. The deeper it gets into the system, the greater the risk.

Comment: An example of a constraint that should be checked in both the app and the db:  Data left NULL where it's not allowed.  The overhead in each place is miniscule.  By disallowing NULL up in the app, the app can get back to the user, if the user left something out of a form, without making a round trip to the db server.  By disallowing NULL in the DB, the DB protects itself against rogue applications,  or even against a DBA that's using interactive SQL to edit a database manually.  An example of something that should be checked only in the DB:  referential integrity.

Comment: @James. Think we are having difficulty over the concept of protection. If the rules are in the db, then from a protective point of view rules in the service layer are doubled (not necessarily a bad thing). If they aren't then there's no doubling up. Perhaps an example that prompted you to ask the question would be a useful context. I'm think the answer will be It depends.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson the example I gave in the question is actually a classic one (and also a real one I have). I have an email field in the database with a unique constraint to stop duplicate emails being added. I also have a check at application level which queries the database for duplicates. It's this piece of duplication I am concerned about. If the validation was more advanced than this e.g. the database validates unique emails, but the service validates email is a `@domain.com` one then I can understand that.

Comment: From reading the answers/comments I can see that there isn't going to be a one size fits all type solution. It has to be evalulated on a *per scenario* basis. However, I thought it would be good to get other peoples suggestions/experiences on how they usually handle that sort of thing.

Comment: In your email case, I'm not sure I would validate that at the service level. Can't see much benefit given the unique constraint exists on the DB. However id I was trying to be "DB" agnostic, atomicity of the check and insert operation would pretty much leave us with a validation. So it would be big picture time I think.

Comment: At least in the c#/Java world, a constraint error will often throw an exception from the driver up several layers back to the business tier. To me this is far less elegant (and slower) than a simple `SELECT` (plus the DB constraint as a safeguard). Also, you limit the ability to perform checks at a time other than the `INSERT`. For example, maybe you are building a registration wizard and you want to validate the username several steps before you actually commit the record (as well as when it is committed). But I agree that it varies by situation.

Answer (score 2):

Please don't do that.

Implementing even "simple" constraints such as keys is decidedly non-trivial in a concurrent environment. For example, it is not enough to query the database in one step and allow the insertion in another only if the first step returned empty result - what if a concurrent transaction inserted the same value you are trying to insert (and committed) **in between** your steps one and two? You have a *race condition* that could lead to duplicated data. Probably the simplest solution for this is to have a global lock to serialize transactions, but then scalability goes out of the window...

Similar considerations exist for other combinations of INSERT / UPDATE / DELETE operations on keys, as well as other kinds of constraints such as foreign keys and even CHECKs in some cases.

DBMSes have devised *very* clever ways over the decades to be both correct and performant in situations like these, yet allow you to easily define constraints in **declarative** manner, minimizing the chance for mistakes. And all the applications accessing the same database will automatically benefit from these centralized constraints.

If you absolutely must choose which layer of code shouldn't validate the data, the database should be your *last* choice.

> So, is it correct to always ensure data going to the persistance layer is indeed "valid" (service layer) or is it more natural to let the invalid data get to the database and handle the error?

Never assume correct data and always validate at the database level, as much as you can.

Whether to *also* validate in upper layers of code depends on a situation, but in the case of key violations, I'd let the database do the heavy lifting.

Comment: +1 for the point regarding concurrency/race condition as it's probably something people forget about at that level. Just to clarify though I am not saying *don't* validate your database - I think it's a crime not to. What I am asking is really should you always have a layer of validation which essentially replicates the same rules which the DB is designed to handle.

Comment: @James Depends on a situation. Sometimes you can't _really_ re-implement database constraint (as with keys), so you should leave that to the database and not try to repeat it. Sometimes it's fairly easy to re-implement (such as a simple CHECK), in which case you might want to do that purely for the user experience. Sometimes its much easier to implement a constraint at the application level (e.g. some cases with inheritance, presence of required attributes in EAV etc.), so it might actually be justified to make an exception and implement the rule only at the application level.

Comment: If you consider the example I gave in the question - I am wondering if it's actually *more* work to query the database (esp if it's a decent size) for the duplicate than it would be to let the database hit the violation. I guess it would need to be tested & benchmarked. However, then it begs the question is it a good idea to let it get that far if you *know* it is going to fail...

Comment: @James It's certainly more work - you are simply adding new processing (the query) on top of the existing processing (the database key enforcement), so it _must_ take more time. And if you need to query the database then you don't _yet know_ it's going to fail. If you can somehow determine it's going to fail without querying the database (e.g. e-mail format is incorrect), then more power to you - you can skip one database round-trip altogether...

Comment: @James Al in all, I think keys and foreign keys should be left to the database and the upper layers should just let the database hit the violation. Simple CHECKs might worthwhile reimplementing in upper layers, to avoid unnecessary database round-trips and for the user experience. And some complex validations might exist only at the application level (especially if you need DBMS-agnostic solution, so would like to avoid putting too much logic in triggers and stored procedures).

Comment: @James BTW, there may be more exceptions to that. For example, what if user needs to upload a large picture together with his/her e-mail? It's probably better to pre-validate "cheap" fields as much as you can, instead of just uploading the whole picture BLOB, and then have it discarded by the database for a key or NOT NULL violation on e-mail. In some small percentage of cases, this might still happen for concurrency reasons, but if you can prevent the bandwidth waste in most cases you are still OK. So there are no cut-and-dry rules, it all depends on the situation...

Comment: "*if you need to query the database then you don't yet know it's going to fail*" - good point, however, I didn't really word my last point correctly, what I meant was if there is a possibility it *could* fail, is it worth checking. I agree with the foreign contraints etc I wouldn't validate that sort of thing at application level and definitely agree doing simple checks (see my comment on @TimMedora's answer). So, I guess there is no *best practise* or one solution fits approach to something like this.

Comment: @James _"if there is a possibility it could fail, is it worth checking"_ How great is that probability and how great is the price of failure (such as wasted bandwidth on BLOB upload)? If both are great, validate early. If one of them is great, benchmark and decide. If both are small, don't validate early.

Answer (score 1):

Two reasons to do it. The db may be accessed from another application..

You might make a wee error in your code, and put data in the db, which because your service layer operates on the assumption that this could never happen, makes it fall over if you are lucky, silent data corruption being worst case.

I've always looked at rules in the DB as backstop for that exceptionally rare occasion when I make a mistake in the code. :)

The thing to remember, is if you need to , you can always relax a constraint, tightening them after your users have spent a lot of effort entering data will be far more problematic.

Be real wary of that word never, in IT, it means much sooner than you wished.

Comment: I am not asking whether you should validate your database - that's a must, I am asking whether you should *protect* it at the service layer from known violations rather than letting the database handle the error and send it back.

Comment: @James. Apologies, I read your question as removing the rules in the DB, not the service layer. I wouldn't call service layer validations protection, if the DB rules were present. I usually look at that issue from the point of convenience. Either I'm already sure I have a customer (multi user might step and change that), or I check for a null, because it's quicker and neater than trapping a foreign key violation for instance.